# Solving for potential outside a square with outgoing flux condition?

Tags: differential-equations, mesh, finite-element-method

### Context

> As a follow up/ simplification of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164141/1089) I would like to **compute the potential created by a charged square** outside of the square. I would like to  impose that far enough the outgoing  flux behaves as though the cube was a point mass.

Let me define a region between a square and a disk as

```
reg = 
 RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]]
```

and extract a mesh out of it

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let me try and solve of the Laplacian, aiming to fix the 
potential on the square **and** the outgoing flux on the disk

```
  edge = DirichletCondition[1, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]]
```

so that

```
  sol = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] ==
   NeumannValue[1, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 2]], edge}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

I get this error message

```
NDSolveValue::femibcnd: No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue
was specified for {u}; the result may not be unique.
```

and the plot looks wrong  (it does not have the symmetry of the problem
and the values are very large).

```
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh], AspectRatio -> 1,Contours -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Question

> What am I doing wrong with the boundary condition?

I am guessing this is some trivial issue but...?
I would be great if the preprocessing of mathematica could guide (more) the user in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     NeumannValue[1, x^2 + y^2 > 2^2], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Contours -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: @chris, fixed the `^2` issue. I did look at the question - but I do not understand it.

Comment: @chris, I'll have a look tomorrow.